# Is there a deep reason why replacing $\cos(x)$ with $e^{ix}$ and taking the real part often makes a contour integral work out?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm grading a complex analysis course right now and it turns out to involve a lot of contour integration.  For instance, students are asked to find the integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (ax)}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} \, dx$$

where $a, b > 0$ are real parameters.  This can be done as follows:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (ax)}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} \, dx
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (ax)}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} \, dx \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iax}}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} \, dx\right] \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \left[\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{iax}}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} \, dx\right].
\end{align}

Now

$$\int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{iax} \, dx}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} = \oint_{L_R+C_R} \frac{e^{iaz}\, dz}{(z^2 + b^2)^2} - \oint_{C_R} \frac{e^{iaz} \, dz}{(z^2 + b^2)^2}$$

where $L_R$ is the line segment going from $-R$ to $R$ and $C_R$ is the circular arc with center 0 going from $R$ to $-R$.

By the residue theorem,
$$\oint_{L_R+C_R} \frac{e^{iaz}\, dz}{(z^2 + b^2)^2} = 2 \pi i \operatorname{res}_{z=bi} \left[\frac{e^{iaz}}{(z^2 + b^2)^2}\right] = \frac{\pi e^{-ab} (1 + ab)}{2 b^3}$$
for $R > b$.  Further, by Jordan's lemma
\begin{align}
\left|\left|\oint_{C_R} \frac{e^{iaz} \, dz}{(z^2 + b^2)^2}\right|\right|
&\leq \frac{\pi}{a} \max_{z \in C_r} \left|\left|\frac{1}{(z^2 + b^2)^2}\right|\right| = \frac{\pi}{a(R^2 + b^2)^2} \to 0
\end{align}
as $R \to 0$, from which we see that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (ax)}{(x^2 + b^2)^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi e^{-ab} (1 + ab)}{4 b^3}.$$

---

Suppose, however, that instead of writing $\cos(a x)$ as $\operatorname{Re}[e^{i x}]$ and pulling the $\operatorname{Re}$ outside the integral we'd tried to do things the same way directly.  The problem in this case is that the integral
$$\oint_{C_R} \frac{\cos(az)}{(z^2 + b^2)^2}$$ doesn't vanish as $R \to \infty$.  By adding an extra term to our equation, though, we managed to make things work out quite nicely.

---

If I try to distill the general technique here, it's something like this: We had a function $f(z)$ for which 
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{C_R} f(z) \, dz$$
didn't vanish, so we found a function $g(z)$ which vanished along $L_R$ and for which
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{C_R} f(z) + g(z) \, dz$$
vanished.  However, it seems incredibly fortuitous that we had such a readily available choice for $g$.  Is this just a consequence of picking a homework problem that can actually be done with pencil in paper in a reasonable amount of time?  Or is something deeper going on?

**Specific questions:**

1. Given a function $f$, is there any nice way of rephrasing the condition that
   $$\oint_{C_R} f(z)\, dz \to 0 \text{ as } R \to \infty$$ as a more straightforward property of $f$?  (At first I wondered if $C_R$ was "a closed curve around $\infty$ in the limit" but this doesn't seem to be right.)
2. Given a meromorphic function $f$ such that $$\oint_{C_R} f(z)\, dz \not \to 0 \text{ as } R \to \infty,$$ can we always find a meromorphic function $g$ such that $g|_\mathbb{R} = 0$ and $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{C_R} f(z) + g(z) =0?$$
3. If not, are there any nice constraints on $f$ that make it possible?  If so, how many such $g$ are there, and can we construct one of them easily?
4. Same questions as above with $L_R$ and $C_R$ replaced by more general curves.

Comment: For the first question, the answer is "Yes," as explained in [THIS LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) to a Wikipedia article on Jordan's Lemma.

Comment: No offense but I'm a little suspicious of your statement that the integral with the $\cos(az)$ in the numerator diverges. Consider rephrasing the original problem as: find the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax) + i\sin(ax)}{(x^2 + b^2)^2}$. The imaginary part of that integral vanishes by virtue of the fact that $\sin(ax)$ is an odd function. (cont. below)

Comment: Therefore, adding the imaginary part, which is to say, writing the $\cos$ as the real part of the complex exponential in your example, didn't change anything. Adding 0 to any intermediate step couldn't have transformed a divergent result into a finite one, which is why I think no intermediate step could be divergent in your derivation of the result without the complex exponential.

Comment: @wltrup: Sorry, I meant to say that $\oint_{C_R} \frac{\cos(az) \, dz}{(z^2+b^2)^2}$ doesn't vanish as $R \to \infty$, not that it diverges.  I've fixed that sentence in the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. For a moment there I thought I was crazy. Anyway, I suspect that you can still use just the $\cos(az)$ if you choose a different contour. In other words, I think all that adding the imaginary part buys you is the ability to use that particular contour you chose.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I read through the article, but I don't see any condition mentioned there other than Jordan's lemma itself.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Read the "Remarks."

Comment: @wltrup: I don't think you can use a different contour, at least not in the sense here where the contour splits up into two pieces with the integral along one vanishing in the limit.  The function $$f(z)= \frac{\cos(az)}{(z^2+b^2)}$$ has poles at $z = \pm bi$, and the residues are
$$\operatorname{res}_{z = \pm bi} f(z) = \pm \frac{e^{ab}(ab-1) - e^{-ab}(ab+1)}{8 b^3} i.$$
So the integral isn't equal to $2 \pi i$ times some combination of the residues.

Comment: @Dr.MV: The only thing I see there is that the integral along $C_R$ vanishes in the limit if $\lim_{R \to \infty} M_R = 0$.  But that's just the case of Jordan's lemma where it establishes that the contour vanishes.  It's not an if-and-only-if condition, and it's also not a "nice" condition, in the sense of being, say, local at $\infty$ or something.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury The passage provides a set of sufficient conditions on $f$ for which $\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: I understand that.  I even used it in the question.  That's not what I asked for, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason. The exponential $e^{iz}$ is bounded in the upper half plane with $|e^{iz}| = e^{-\Im z}$, which tends to $0$ uniformly at $\Im z\rightarrow\infty$. And $e^{-iz}$ is bounded and decays in the lower half plane. However, $\cos(z)$ is not bounded in either half plane.

If you have a bounded real differentiable function $g(t)$ on the real axis, then you can define
\begin{align}
    H(z)  & = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{1+tz}{t-z}\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}} \\
          & = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)\left[\frac{1}{t-z}-\frac{t}{1+t^{2}}\right]dt.
\end{align}
$H$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{H(z)}=H(\overline{z})$. For $y > 0$,
$$
              \frac{H(x+iy)-H(x-iy)}{2i}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{g(t)y}{(t-y)^{2}+y^{2}}dt.
$$
Therefore,
$$
                  \lim_{y\downarrow 0}\Im H(x+iy)=g(x)
$$
The function $H$ is bounded on $|\Im z| \ge \epsilon > 0$. So if you start with a function $g$ that has a bounded holomorphic extension to a strip $|\Im z| < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$--such as with $\cos(t)$--then you get this kind of thing in general where there is a bounded holomprhic function $H_{+}(z)$ on a neighborhood of the upper half plane, and a bounded holomorphic function $H_{-}(z)$ on a neighborhood of the lower half plane such that $\Re H_{+}(t)=\Re H_{-}(t) = g(t)$.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, perhaps *that* is the question you should be asking (as explicitly as possible.)

Comment: @DanielMcLaury : I've added more to explain why this sort of thing is to be expected, and some conditions under which it does.

Comment: For my own future reference: apparently if I take 
$$g(t) = \frac{\cos(a t)}{(t^2 + b^2)^2}$$
then I get
$$H(t) = \frac{e^{-ab} [(a b +1) z^3 + (3b^2-ab^3) z]}{2b^3(b^2+z^2)^2} + i \frac{e^{i a z}}{(b^2 + z^2)^2}$$

Comment: @DanielMcLaury : Or, you may apply the construction to the $\cos$ function only, and allow the rest to come along as a multiplier. Lots of choices.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the intuitive meaning of this formula? I'm sure it's obvious to an analyst, but it's not quite so clear to me. Should I think of it as a mobius transformation and a factor that dies off at infinity?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt$ is the Cauchy integral, but you can improve its ability to deal with more functions $f$ if you subtract away the integral where $z$ is replaced by $i$ (or some other point not on the real axis.) This improves $t$ convergence as $\frac{1}{t-z}-\frac{1}{t-i}=(z-i)\frac{1}{(t-i)(t-z)}$ has a second order decay. You can repeat this process by subtracting $\frac{1}{(t-i)(t-i)}$. The most symmetric form is where you subtract $\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{t-i}+\frac{1}{t+i}\right]$, which is a real term. Is that what you're asking about?